# All Ajax request 419 after using Intervention\Image on Laravel 5.7

Tags: php, laravel, image, intervention

First I'm sorry cause I asked this question. Maybe it dublicated or wrong place to ask. I'm beginer at Laravel, Vuejs. My stuck here:

First i gonna install Intervention/Image, it's woring normally and i can upload image to the website (and the S3).

But for a few hours later, i can't upload, and all the Post request Ajax in others page return 419 Error (unknown error); with messsage "" and the path `Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException`.

I checked clearly that in the header of request have "X-CSRF-TOKEN" already.

I finded on the internet but it seems I was the first to encounter this problem. I'm stucked here for two days. And website of intervention can't connect now with 100% ping fail.

I'm sure about first time I install this working normally, but then all Post request get error, althought Get request working normally.

I'm already remove this by `composer` then install again, but notthing changed. So if someone was get this stuck and has fixed this or have difference solutions, please help me by your suggestions. All I need is upload image, resize, and then up to S3 server.

I'm using Laravel 5.7, intervention/image version 2.4.2

This is my code upload in Controller:

```
    if ($rq->hasFile('image')) {
        $save_path = 'upload/'.\Auth::user()->username.'/images/';

        $image      = $rq->file('image');
        $fileName   = time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();

        $img = Image::make($image->getRealPath());
        $img->stream();
        // dd();
        Storage::disk('s3')->put($save_path.$fileName, $img->__toString(), 'public');
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: can u try to add api in `verifyCsrtToken` middleware then check laravel give 419 or not

Comment: @JigneshJoisar thanks for your suggest

Answer (score 1):

In the file `app\Http\Kernel.php` comment out this line,

```
// \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
```

this will confirm you that the issue is with the CSRF token and not the intervention package.

you should not keep it commented out. it's just so you know exactly where the issue is. maybe it's a cookies issue. missing key in the `.env` file. etc..

Comment: Thanks for your answer